# Percentage of amount in a subdocument grouped per type in Mongoose/NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following MongoDB schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Email is required.']
},
transactions: [
    {
        categoryName: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Category name in transaction is required.']
        },
        categoryType: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Category type in transaction is required.']
        },
        amount: {
            type: Number,
            required: [true, 'Transaction amount is required.']
        }
    }
]})
```

`transactions.categoryType` can only be `Income` or `Expense`. Now per queried `_id`, I want to return the ratio/percentage of `transactions.CategoryName` per `Income` and `Expense`. Meaning if I have the following data:

```
 {
    "_id": 000001, 
     "email": "asdasd@email.com"
    "transactions": [
        {
            "categoryName": "Food",
            "categoryType": "Expense",
            "amount": 200
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "Rent",
            "categoryType": "Expense",
            "amount": 1000
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "Salary",
            "categoryType": "Income",
            "amount": 15000
        }
    ]
}
```

the result that I would want is:

```
{ "email": "asdasd@email.com",
  "Income": [["Salary", 100]],
  "Expense": [["Food", 16.67],["Rent",83.33]],
}
```

Now, I have the following query:

```
    return User.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id : ObjectId(request.params.id) } },
    { $unwind : "$transactions"},
    { $group : { _id : { type: "$transactions.categoryType" },
                         total: {$sum : "$transactions.amount"},
                         transactionsArray: { $push: "$transactions"}
                }
    },  
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        transactionsArray:1,
        type: "$_id.type",
        total:1
       }
    }
])
```

which returns a data like this:

```
[
{
    "total": 1200,
    "transactions": [
        {
            "categoryName": "Food",
            "categoryType": "Expense",
            "amount": 200,
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "Rent",
            "categoryType": "Expense",
            "amount": 1000,
        }
    ],
    "type": "Expense"
},
{
    "total": 15000,
    "transactions": [
        {
            "categoryName": "Salary",
            "categoryType": "Income",
            "amount": 15000,
        }
    ],
    "type": "Income"
}
]
```

Now, I do not know how am I going to further process the result set to divide the `transactions.amount` by the `total` to get the result that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may go with multiple steps in aggregations

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$group`- first group to group by `_id` and `$categoryType`. So we can get the total amount and an amount for particular transaction. This helps to  calculate the ratio.
- `$map` helps to loop over the array and calculate the ratio
  `$reduce`- You need comma separated string array of objects. So loop it and get the structure.
- `$group` to group by `_id` only so we can get the key value pair of category type and Income/Expense when we push
- `$replaceRoot` to make the `$grp` object as root which should be merged with already existing fields (`$mergeObjects`)
- `$project` for remove unwanted fields

Here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$transactions" },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": { id: "$_id", catType: "$transactions.categoryType" },
      "email": { "$first": "$email" },
      "amount": { "$sum": "$transactions.amount" },
      "category": {
        $push: { k: "$transactions.categoryName", v: "$transactions.amount" }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      category: {
        $map: {
          input: "$category",
          in: {
            k: "$$this.k",
            v: {
              "$multiply": [
                { "$divide": [ "$$this.v","$amount" ]},
                100
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      category: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$category",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              [
                [ "$$this.k", { $toString: "$$this.v" } ]
              ],
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.id",
      "email": { "$first": "$email" },
      "grp": { "$push": { k: "$_id.catType", v: "$category" } }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [ {  "$arrayToObject": "$grp" }, "$$ROOT" ]
      }
    }
  },
  { "$project": { grp: 0 } }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FdmYQGhpMuZ)**

Comment: Thank you! works perfect! One last question though, let say there's a new dateAdded property for each object in the transactions array? how do I put a condition that limits the transactions that will be included within a certain dateAdded range? thanks in advance